# What is the easiest way to transparently compress directories on ext4 in lxd container (btrfs mounted)?

Tags: ext4, btrfs, lxc, lxd

What is the easiest way to compress directories transparently on **lxd** container server with **ext4** file-system when the lxd/**lxc** is mounted on **btrfs** file system with btrfs **RAID1**?

The container has tons of data (approx. 1TB) with potential duplication. I do not have enough space to even take a on-site snapshot.

Comment: btrfs has built-in support for several compression algorithms. Is this what you're referring to? https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Compression

Comment: btrfs has built-in translation if started with the compress flag. However, the container  running on btrfs has ext4 file system so I am not sure if that will help.

Comment: Are you saying that the container is using a ext4 filesystem image file which is stored on a BTRFS filesystem?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes, the container is using a ext4 filesystem image file which is stored on a BTRFS filesystem.